# Can I refactor if - else with a switch or case statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var btns1 = {
    'Submit': function (win) {
        submitHandler(oLink.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
    },
    'Submit & Close': function (win) {
        submitHandler(oLink.$link, $('#main-form'), true);
    },
    'Close': function (win) {
        modal.closeModal()
    }
}
var btns2 = {
    'Submit & Close': function (win) {
        submitHandler(oLink.$link, $('#main-form'), true);
    },
    'Close': function (win) {
        modal.closeModal()
    }
}

if (oLink.title.substr(0, 4) == "Crea") {
    if (content.match(/data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/)) {
        oLink.title += " " + content.match(/data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/)[1]
    }
    var btns = btns1;
}
if (oLink.title.substr(0, 4) == "Edit") {
    var btns = btns1;
}
if (oLink.title.substr(0, 4) == "Dele") {
    var btns = btns2;
}
```

Is there a way that I could refactor the code. What I was thinking was to put this into a function called "adminModalBtns", have it take oLink and content as a parameter and have it return btns. Would it be most clear to do this with if-else or a case statement?

Comment: just store `oLink.title.substr(0, 4)` to a variable and compare with it instead. Also introduce `else if` instead of bunch of `if`. PS: if `Crea` and `Dele` is enough for you - you could use `C`, `E`, `D` instead

Comment: Would a case statement be clearer. Actually I am not sure is it case or switch in javascript. Normally I code in C# and Java each language seemes different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getButtons(oLink, content) {

    var btns1 = {
        'Submit': function(win) {
            submitHandler(oLink.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
        }
    }
    var btns2 = {
        'Submit & Close': function(win) {
            submitHandler(oLink.$link, $('#main-form'), true);
        },
        'Close': function(win) {
            modal.closeModal()
        }
    }
    switch (oLink.title.substr(0, 4)) {
    case "Crea":
        if (content.match(/data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/)) {
            oLink.title += " " + content.match(/data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/)[1]
        }
    case "Edit":
        return $.extend(btns1, btns2);
    case "Dele":
        return btns2;
    }
}

var btns = getButtons(oLink, content);
```

Comment: Thanks for this really nice solution. If I was to specify the function as "function adminModalBtns() {  }" Would I still be able to code the last line of your example in the same way? Also one small thing. I need to pass in the "oLink and content" to the function as I need to match content and get the oLink.title.

Comment: it may not be the exact solution you need, buy you can build on this

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var sub = oLink.title.substr(0, 4)
   ,bttns =  sub === "Crea" ? btns1 
           : sub === "Edit" ? btns1 
           : btns2;
oLink.title += /data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/.test(content) 
               ? ' ' + content.match(/data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/)[1] 
               : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also refactor your code by using a hash map `conditionMap` and create a variable `re` to store the regular expression `/data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/`:

```
var getButtons = function (oLink, content) {
        var re = new RegExp(/data-RowKey="(.{3}).*/),
            btns1 = {
                'Submit': function (win) {
                    submitHandler(oLink.$link, $('#main-form'), false);
                }
            },
            btns2 = {
                'Submit & Close': function (win) {
                    submitHandler(oLink.$link, $('#main-form'), true);
                },
                'Close': function (win) {
                    modal.closeModal();
                }
            },
            conditionMap = {
                'Crea': (content.match(re)) && (oLink.title += ' ' + content.match(re)[1]),
                'Edit': $.extend(btns1, btns2),
                'Dele': btns2
            };

        return conditionMap[oLink.title.substr(0, 4)];
    },
    btns = getButtons(oLink, content);
```